# How can I add a save button in my page variant?

Tags: 7, forms, panels, display-suite

I have created two variants of **user edit** page, one displays the entire form and other displays only a couple of fields of that form.

I have created a selection rule so that one triggers when is needed and other runs as default form mode.

But the problem is the first variant, which only have two fields doesn't have any save button.

This is what my panels look like:
[image]

This is what I did with that variant:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with recent activity => [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1399058)

Solution:

After you apply the latest patch to ctools, you need to add a "User form actions / buttons" element to your page.
[image]

Your page variant should look sth like this:

[image]

And the rendered form now comes with a submit button:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Although I fixed this with a little 'hack', I will apply patch later :)